How do industrial robots, specifically those using Cartesian motion commands like moveL, perform trajectory planning at the firmware level?
How do industrial robots, specifically those using Cartesian motion commands like moveL, perform trajectory planning at the firmware level? I'm interested in the underlying algorithms and considerations. My current understanding is that,

Defining the desired path, a straight line in this case
Determining the speed and acceleration at each interpolated point in cartesian space along the path, using a trapezoidal or s-curve velocity profile.
Orientation interpolation with SLERP.
Converting Cartesian positions and orientations into joint angles with IK(analytical), converting Cartesian Velocities into joint velocities with Jacobian.
Sending joint angle commands to the robot controller.

My questions are:

Given that collision avoidance is typically a higher-level concern, are there any basic collision checks or safety mechanisms built into the firmware-level trajectory planning?
Are there any open-source or commercial libraries or frameworks that provide reference implementations or building blocks for Cartesian trajectory planning in robotics?

Thanks in advance!
